# Other than create products, price and langauage management, what HMS IAP PMS can do?

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-iap, huawei-mobile-services

HUAWEI IAP provides a product management system (PMS) for managing the prices and languages of in-app products (including games) in multiple locations. Other than thses two catagories that developers can use directly in Huawei App Gallary, are there other functions PMS provides and how can developers use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Product Management System (PMS) API](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agcapi-pms-api-overview) allows you to create and update product and promotion information, including the product price and display language, implementing in-app management of product prices and display languages for localized pricing for global locations.

1. Creating Products: Including Creating a Non-Subscription Product (Consumables and Non-consumables) and Creating a Subscription Product (auto-renewable)
2. Querying Products: You can call the [Querying Details of a Product](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getproductdetailinfo) API to query a specific product based on the app ID and product ID or call the [Querying Products by Criteria](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-getproductinfo) API to query all products that meet the criteria that you have specified, for example, all products in a specified app and all products in a specified subscription group, which can be sorted by attribute.
3. Updating Product Information: Basic product information includes the product name, language, price, and status. You can call the [Updating a Product](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-updateproduct) or [Updating Products in Batches](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-batchupdateproduct) API to update basic product information.
4. Managing Product Statuses: The status of a product is specified when it is created. You can then call the [Activating Products in Batches](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-batchactiveproduct) or [Deactivating Products in Batches](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-batchdeactiveproduct) API to update product statuses in batches.
5. Managing Product Promotion Information: You can call the [Creating Product Promotion Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-addpromotion) API to create product promotion information for both subscription and non-subscription products, including the including the promotion time period, applicable countries/regions, and promotional prices. To update the information, call the [Updating Product Promotion Information](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-updatepromotion) API.

Comment: Thanks Shirley for the complete set of info.。